# How to find Azure VM applied backup protection policy name via Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

How to find which azure backup protection policy applied on specific Azure virtual machine via Powershell

Get- AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy asking for policyname but there are many policy under one service vault.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use following script.

```
##Replace Recovery service vault name
Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -Name "shui" | Set-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVaultContext

##FriendlyName is your Azure VM name
$namedContainer=Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType "AzureVM" -Status "Registered" -FriendlyName "shui"

$item = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $namedContainer -WorkloadType "AzureVM"
$item.ProtectionPolicyName
```

Comment: How can i find set of configuration associated with backuppolicy?  like backup frequency, retention etc...

Comment: @vj54 You could use `Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy -name <>|fl` to list all object. You could see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47537916/find-azure-backup-retention-associated-with-backup-policy/47543748#47543748