# Find Azure backup/retention associated with backup policy

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I can get backup policy name via : [How to find Azure VM applied backup protection policy name via Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47511805/how-to-find-azure-vm-applied-backup-protection-policy-name-via-powershell) BUT looking to find actual configuration associated with backuppolicy like following data :

BACKUP FREQUENCY

Daily at 00:00
RETENTION RANGE

Retention of daily backup point

Retain backup taken every day at 00:00 for 7 Day(s)
Retention of weekly backup point

Retain backup taken every week on Saturday at 00:00 for 4 Week(s)
Retention of monthly backup point

Retain backup taken every month on First Saturday at 00:00 for 12 Month(s)
Retention of yearly backup point

Retain backup taken every year in January on First Saturday at 00:00 for 99 Year(s)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy|fl` to get them.

For example:

```
##Replace Recovery service vault name
Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -Name "shui" | Set-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVaultContext

##FriendlyName is your Azure VM name
$namedContainer=Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType "AzureVM" -Status "Registered" -FriendlyName "shui"
$item = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $namedContainer -WorkloadType "AzureVM"

$policyname=$item.ProtectionPolicyName
$policy=Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy -Name $policyname

##BACKUP FREQUENCY
$policy.SchedulePolicy
##RETENTION RANGE
$policy.RetentionPolicy
```

Comment: I am glad to hear it. Maybe you could vote up my answer --:)

Comment: Thanks for the solution :)